# Debugging with gdb on a program with no optimization but still there is no symbol in the current context for local variables

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc, gdb

I've been having this problem for while now, but always seem to put off asking this question because it seems like I am doing something wrong... but right now I feel otherwise... taken this code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  if(argc < 2)
  {
    std::cout << "usage: " << argv[0] << " <string>" << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  std::string str = argv[1];
  std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
  std::cout << str << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled with the command:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall main.cpp -o main -O0 -ggdb3
```

I am using a very recent trunk version of gcc, I the trunk was taken around September 23rd ish... Also note that I am not compiling with optimization!

Now anyway, I start debugging, like this:

```
gdb --quiet --args ./main string
```

I set a break point at line 12 (the reverse algorithm)

```
b 12
```

then I run the program

```
run
```

then I try to print out the string, to see what it is

```
print str
```

And this, my dear friends, is what seems strange to me:
The output of that previous command is:

```
No symbol "str" in current context.
```

a quick check to the local variables doesn't show the string either

```
info locals
```

all I get is

```
std::__ioinit = {static _S_refcount = 2, static _S_synced_with_stdio = true}
```

so I'm wondering, am I at fault, or is the compiler or debugger at fault... this has been a pretty pain in the ass problem for a long time for me... so thanks for even reading this question... :)

EDIT: now that it has become clear that there is something wrong with my gcc build, I'm wondering if anyone has come across a bug report or any other case where there seems to a be a problem similar to this... I will also try checking with a recent build of gdb to make sure that there is definitely not a problem with my current debugger (that comes with ubuntu)... does that make sense?

EDIT2: So after compiling gdb v7.5, I got relatively the same result except there were no locals present at all... I guess that means it's a gcc issue, thanks everyone...

Comment: I've never seen GCC do this, but MS compilers will often, when it is legal to do so, defer creating objects until they are first used.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz hm, that's interesting...

Comment: I am having this exact same problem, Ubuntu 12.04 x64. I don't know what to do - the only local is `std::__ioinit`. It's very annoying, I cannot debug...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, even with --quiet it works for me. Maybe there's something wrong with your setup.

```
~/tmp $ g++ -Wall tmp.cpp -o tmp -O0 -ggdb3
~/tmp $ gdb --quiet --args ./tmp string
Reading symbols from /xxxxxxxx/tmp...done.
(gdb) b 12
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400c95: file tmp.cpp, line 12.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /xxxxxxxx/tmp string
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffdc58) at tmp.cpp:12
12        std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
(gdb) print str
$1 = "string"
(gdb) info locals
str = "string"
(gdb)
```

Comment: I have compiler version (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) and without --quiet all works.

Comment: Btw, CrazyCasta with -ggdb3 i dont see any additional information about variables, very strange

Comment: what about without quiet, did you try that? and is there actually a difference

Comment: alright... the compiler from Ubuntu seems to be working as expected... however my recent build isn't... this must be a bug right?

Comment: got that same version as you DenisErmolin and gdb seems to be working as expected with or without the --quiet option...

Comment: @DenisErmolin not sure what the gdb3 portion of -ggdb3 is about. I just used it to be as close to what he used as possible.

Comment: Yeah i just forgot to run it =) Anyway seems to me its new feature/bug in recent compiler version

Comment: basically -ggdb3 means "compile lots (the 3) of gdb specific debugging symbols"

Comment: @DenisErmolin I'm sure it's a bug in gcc, but I am going to test with a newer version of gdb to make sure the new compiler is not doing any crap the old debugger can't handle...

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely provided the correct answer to this problem (with gcc >= 4.8, you either need to use GDB >=7.5 or compile with '-g -gdwarf-2').

Answer (score 87):

As noted in the [release notes for GCC 4.8](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html) (i.e. current trunk):

> DWARF4 is now the default when generating DWARF debug information. When -g is used on a platform that uses DWARF debugging information, GCC will now default to -gdwarf-4 -fno-debug-types-section.
>   GDB 7.5, Valgrind 3.8.0 and elfutils 0.154 debug information consumers support DWARF4 by default. Before GCC 4.8 the default version used was DWARF2. To make GCC 4.8 generate an older DWARF version use -g together with -gdwarf-2 or -gdwarf-3. The default for Darwin and VxWorks is still -gdwarf-2 -gstrict-dwarf.

So you need to use GDB 7.5 or compile with `-g -gdwarf-2`

Comment: This is the correct answer which solved my debugging woes for GCC 4.8 w/gdb 7.4 - thanks @Johnathan

Comment: That solved my problems :) I was using gcc 4.8.1 with gdb 7.4-2012.04

Comment: Solved my woes with GCC 4.9.2 (built from source) and GDB 7.2-83.el6 (from CentOS 6.7).

Comment: still did not fix it for me. I suppose the answer might be out of date? Is there a similar solution for today?

Comment: @lotolmencre, the answer is not out of date