# Call arguments missing when debugging with ndk-gdb. Stack trace works

Tags: android, c, debugging, android-ndk, gdb

I am trying to debug native code on Android using ndk-gdb, with mixed results.

When the debugger hits a breakpoint, I am able to get a nice stack trace using 'bt'.
Hhen typing 'info source', ndk-gdb tells me that the file I have hit the breakpoint in is "Compiled with DWARF 2 debugging format".

The problem arises when I enter 'info args' to get the function argument values. ndk-gdb then states that: "No symbol table info available.".

Any input to the cause of this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a guess, have you used -g option during build?

Comment: Doing an 'objdump -W' yields:
'<c>   DW_AT_producer    : (indirect string, offset: 0x12f6): GNU C 4.8 -mbionic -march=armv7-a -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -marm -mtls-dialect=gnu -g -Os -O0 -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -fno-omit-frame-pointer'.

Comment: We have found a solution:
Using the gcc 4.6 toolchain works, while the gcc 4.8 toolchain yields the problem we have seen.

Comment: That works for me too. Still would want to use 4.8 though.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that it says that about the file being compiled with DWARF 2 format, because the flags you provide there indicates it is only specifying -g, which should get GCC 4.8 to produce DWARF 4 format. Which also is consistent with the error you are seeing. Add the flag `-gdwarf-2` and the NDK debugger (which is not yet at version 7.5) should be able to deal with the symbols.

I picked this up from one of the answers to this question:  [Debugging with gdb on a program with no optimization but still there is no symbol in the current context for local variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595631/debugging-with-gdb-on-a-program-with-no-optimization-but-still-there-is-no-symbo)